# position fixed в рамках родителя

Tags: css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.frame {
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.sec_1 {
  background: #ffe;
}

.sec_2 {
  background: #ffc;
}

.sec_1 .fix {
  top: 20px;
  background: #Fec;
}

.sec_2 .fix {
  background: #Fcc;
}

section {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.fix {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='frame'>
    <main class='main'>
      <section class='sec_1'>
        <div class='fix'>1 fix</div>
        1 sec
      </section>
      <section class='sec_2'>
        <div class='fix'>2 fix</div>
        2 sec
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы с `position: fixed` были по ширине родителя.
В данном примере я не смог добиться того, чего хотел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем проекте каким-то неведомым для меня образом фиксированные элементы прилипли в левому краю родительского элемента (причем явно не было задано какое-либо позиционирование), а правый край выходит за границы элементов и уходит за границу экрана. Я попытался воссоздать структуру и код в примере, но это не удалось. В данном примере фиксированные элементы выходят за границы родителей.
Как сделать, чтобы фиксированные элементы были по ширине родителя. Без объявления ширины в абсолютных единицах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.frame {
  padding: 0 15%;
}

.sec_1 {
  background: #ffe;
}

.sec_2 {
  background: #ffc;
}

.sec_1 .fix {
  
  background: #Fec;
}

.sec_2 .fix {
  background: #Fcc;
}

section {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.fix {
  width: 100%;
  /*какой top  укажешь там эти элементы и зафиксируются*/
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <main class='main'>
      <section class='sec_1'>
        <div class='fix'>1 fix</div>
     sssssssssss
      </section>
      <section class='sec_2'>
        <div class='fix'>2 fix</div>
ssssssssssssss
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
```